# Jumble text on website

Tags: web

My website is coming up with some weird jumbled text.  Has anyone seen this before? [image]

The site is [nextlevelwebworks.com](http://nextlevelwebworks.com).  Is this happening for you too?  Thank you.

Comment: Fine in my browser - looks like your Adobe Browser lab is the issue, or at least there's something causing *it* to display that stuff.

Comment: ty for your feedback.  I used BrowserLab because I was told about the problem by one of my contacts on LinkedIn but couldn't see it from my own IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and IE, and they all turned out the same. What browsers/OS did you try it on?

Comment: The same browsers.  But hey I think I solved the issue now.  There we some Rewrite Rules .htacess file that were conflicting with other settings on the server.  I removed the rules since they were not necessarily important anyways.  Seems all is well now if you or someone can verify on their end.  Thank you all.